# MallformedPolicyDocument. IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM policy following the instructions [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md#iam-policy).

When I try to add this policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

with this command:

```
 aws iam create-role --role-name externaldns --assume-role-policy-document file://external_dns.json
```

I get the following error

```
An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: Has prohibited field Resource
```

I would appreciate guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
            ],
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

you forgot two `,` characters after `"Resource":[],`.